# How to make sure return false; is called after onclick event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on Javascript.I have a situation where i am using an anchor tag like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myFucntion(); return false;">Submit</a>
```

I have used developer tools to debug this issue and found that on-click of Submit , it goes to myFunction(); and executes as expected until end of the function. After that it just shows a blank page and i am not really sure what is happening here.

I can understand if there is any error in myFunction(); then return false will not be called. But i do not see any issues in myFunction();. Did anyone faced this kind of weird problem before? And what could be the possible solution to figure out whats exactly happening after myFunction is executed and to make sure return false; is called after myFunction();?

Note: No Errors are found in console.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Open up your browser's javascript console and see if there are any errors reported.  In addition, you could set a breakpoint in your javascript code and step through it, line by line, using Chrome at least.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the post. No errors found in console :( @James

Comment: Post code of myFunction please

Comment: Any reason the function can't just return false?

Comment: why can't you write return false inside your myFunction at the end of it?

Comment: Is the function name really "myFucntion" and not "myFunction"?

Comment: @TimConsolazio I do not see any reason for not returning false as everything is as expected. But suddenly after the execution of MyFunction it shows a blank page without any errors.

Comment: Sorry may be a typo. Its myFunction(); @Pointy

Comment: What is inside myFucntion()?

Comment: @VivekN Thats a good idea. let me see how that behaves.

Comment: Actually i cant write return false inside MyFcuntion as it is used multiple times. So it will have effect on other places . @VivekN

Comment: Inside MyFucntion it does some process to get the data and which i see is correct while debugging . Is there a way to know if return false is really called? @VivekN

Comment: Please provide all relevant code as per [mcve]. All anyone can do with what little is shown is guess

Comment: You can try doing this.It's just to understand if the statement after myFunction is executed or not.
<a href="#" onclick="myFucntion(); myOtherFunction();">Submit</a>

Create two functions myFucntion and myOtherFunction and console.log inside them and see if both console.log work

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass event to the function and then in your function write

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in the very beginning. this will prevent the default behavior of the anchor tag and do nothing after that your function code will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Shehzad. But i cant do that as myFunciton is used in other places too.

Comment: as far as i got your problem is that you dont want the default behavior of anchor tag ? can you please share you complete code ? may be i can help you in a much better way after watching your code.